# Is there a way to inspect build dir xml-data from bamboo ui

Tags: bamboo

Is there a URL path that bamboo UI exposes which allows you see browser the contents of the build dir ?
All I can see is the url to logs but nothing for the build dir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not directly.

1. You can configure the directory as a job artifact, then it will show up in the UI in the artifacts tab. In this case the URL would be http://myserver/bamboo/browse/MYBUILD/latest/artifact
2. Alternatively, you can run `ls` from within your build and see the contents in the build log. If not already so, you can add a script task to your job for the purpose.

Comment: I have resorted to option 2 `ls -lrt` etc. however the artifact may not be published if the job failed i.e. which is when most of us like to inspect the contents. I am asking does bamboo exposes any settings that enable view into the build dir.

Comment: Interesting point... to my knowledge bamboo will generate (at least in the case of shared artifacts) something providing that you set the pattern to a location that exists even if the tests have failed.

Comment: It seems like only a very few like `CircleCI` allows better insight into the `worker\agent`. My expectations are anyway low on Bamboo so I doubt Bamboo has such capabilities.

Comment: Can you let me know what kind of project you are building and the kind of failure you are getting... and I can have a poke around my bamboo tomorrow... however, yes, more often than not I have walked away feeling a bit sad :(

Comment: Well simple thing I notice is sometimes the Source Repository Checkout step (using Bitbucket) does not pull new changes irrespective of `Force Clean Build`  checkbox and you wonder if the changes really made it. In other cases a directory created by the same Job Stage has permission issues to create more files in it. You don't want `ls -lrt` into your job all the time.